# Array Length 4 doesn't match Index Length 5 error message

Tags: python, pandas

I'm relatively new to pandas and am trying create a moving average crossover trading strategy backtest. It was going well until I tried to retrieve the profitability of long trades by creating a DataFrame. I continue to get the error message "ValueError: array length 4 doesn't match index length 5". Here is the piece of code that is giving me issues.

```
Dextera_long_profits = pd.DataFrame({
        "Price": Dextera_signals.loc[(Dextera_signals["Signal"] == "Buy") &
                                  Dextera_signals["Regime"] == 1, "Price"],
        "Profit": pd.Series(Dextera_signals["Price"] - Dextera_signals["Price"].shift(1)).loc[
            Dextera_signals.loc[(Dextera_signals["Signal"].shift(1) == "Buy") & (Dextera_signals["Regime"].shift(1) == 1)].index
        ].tolist(),
        "End Date": Dextera_signals["Price"].loc[
            Dextera_signals.loc[(Dextera_signals["Signal"].shift(1) == "Buy") & (Dextera_signals["Regime"].shift(1) == 1)].index
        ].index
    })
Dextera_long_profits

print(Dextera_long_profits)
```

Comment: I would suggest reformatting your code so it's a little more readable.

Comment: `&` has higher precedence than `==`, so maybe `(Dextera_signals["Signal"] == "Buy") & Dextera_signals["Regime"] == 1` is evaluating to the wrong value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe one of the .locs is returning 4 values instead of 5.  Try each of these in isolation and you should be able to determine which is the culprit.